# "insert guest additions cd image..." does not do anything

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am using the latest version of VirtualBox (7.0.12) and the latest version of Ubuntu image (v22.04.3).

I installed the Ubuntu Virtual machine by checking the "skip unattended Installation" button Checked.

[image]

**PROBLEM:** I need the Ubuntu VM to run full screen (with correct scaling). I tried to click the `"insert guest additions cd image..."` option but nothing happened afterwards i.e. no new option appears for the virtual screen size.

How can I resize my VM to full-screen?

[image]

Comment: It appears you may have chosen Windows for the guest additions. Is that the case?   Can you back out and reinstall for Ubuntu?   I am not sure here.

Comment: @John: Sorry, I did not understand. I am on Windows-11 OS and trying to create a VM for Ubuntu. I have not downloaded/installed any guest additions separately.

Comment: Please see if this helps:   https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm